# Что делает змея?

Tags: выбор-слова

Недавно один мой знакомый поляк, увидев русское предложение «У тебя в ванной сидит ящерица», очень удивился: «Как же так, почему „сидит“? Она ведь лежит, и по-польски тоже говорится „лежит“». Меня такой вопрос застал врасплох, и я ответил ему, что если она живая, то по-русски надо говорить, что она сидит. Позже я стал вспоминать, какие животные в русском всегда «сидят» – живые насекомые всегда сидят, а вот крокодилы? Наверно, если греются на солнышке, то лежат, в засаде сидят все, даже люди, ну а на берегу, в речке крокодилы сидят или лежат? А змеи? Сколько я не вспоминал, я не вспомнил ни одного случая, когда бы я слышал, чтобы кто-то хоть как-то называл то, что делает змея, скажем, в траве, обычно глагол просто опускается: «Там под кустом змея!» или «Осторожно, тут змея!» Так что же делает змея, сидит или лежит? Ну, и про крокодилов тоже было бы интересно ваше мнение услышать.

Comment: Насолько я понимаю, поляки тоже говорят "змея сидит" в каких-то контекстах, погуглите wąż siedzi - и вот даже и в ванной - http://www.wykop.pl/wpis/7470872/nie-waz-nie-siedzi-w-basenie-z-woda-on-siedzi-pod-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Змея — однозначно **лежит**.
"Вот на камне, пригревшись на солнышке, лежит змея." — так сказал бы я.

> "...он уже достиг раздавив змею в пути **лежащую**..."  [Радищев. Письмо к
> другу, жительствующему в Тобольске, по долгу звания своего (1790)]
>
> "К самому корню древа кесарева **прилег** ядовитый змей, на пагубу юных
> отраслей." [Ф. В. Булгарин. Димитрий Самозванец (1830)]
>
> "В сербских загадках огонь представляется в виде змия: «змея **лежит**,
> где змея лежит, там трава не растет»." [Ф.И. Буслаев. Эпическая поэзия
> (1851)]

Здесь еще интересно вспомнить мультфильм, Песня Львенка и Черепашки:

> "Я на солнышко гляжу,\ \ Всё лежу и лежу,\ \ И на солнышко гляжу."

Если ящерица на спине, то она "лежит на спине".

Черепаха, ящерица, змея есть пресмыкающиеся. То есть при(с)мыкают себя к земле, к тому, по чему ползут. Так что логика в польском сказать про ящерицу, что "она лежит" в траве, есть. В русском в определенном контексте такое тоже есть:

> "Под этот луч то **прилегла ящерица**, зеленая, как ярь" [И. И.
> Лажечников. Басурман (1838)]

Черепаха лежит на брюхе. Может ли она сидеть?

Сидеть, внутри объема (другой смысл, чем в OP):

> "Человек издали замечал змею, которая обычно сидела в норе, высунув
> голову" [Юрий Трифонов. Утоление жажды (1959-1962)]
>
> "... ежели ему доведется вместо незлобного голубя посадить в пазуху
> блистательную змею." [Я.П. Козельский. Философические предложения,
> 1768 года]

Answer (score 1):

`Змея лежит в коробке` - я бы это понял как мертвая змея в коробке или недееспособная на данный момент змея.

`Змея сидит в коробке` - однозначно живая змея в коробке.

По аналогии - `Змея сидит в комнате`.

Также `Змея сидит в норе`, но при этом `Змея лежит на тропинке` и `У тебя в комнате змея на полу лежит`. Видимо когда речь идет о объемном пространстве живая змея сидит, а мертвая - лежит. А в случае с плоской поверхностью - змея всегда лежит.

Comment: Тут avtokod по-моему как раз и написал, что если "в объеме" (в норе, в коробке), то сидит, а если "в пространстве" (на дороге), то лежит.

Comment: А, точно, нижние 5 строк просмотрел, выделить бы это, а то создается впечатление что ответ про то, что "однозначно лежит".

Comment: Да, есть такая проблема у длинных ответов :)

Comment: "Змея сидит" -- только в совсем маленьком объёме (в коробке, в норе). А вот в комнате или в террариуме зоопарка -- точно НЕ сидит.

Comment: Змея НАХОДИТСЯ (не лежит и не сидит) в комнате, в серпентарии зоопарка.

Answer (score 0):

На берегу и в реке крокодил однозначно лежит. Змея тоже лежит (в то время, когда не ползёт).